# How to store array in session in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can you please tell me how to store an array in session and how to retrieve that array from session?

I am trying to store one array of type `Double` and assigning values of the same type but it is showing me an error. How do I assign values to the array which is in session?

I am using [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework).

Comment: It would undoubtedly help us to help you if you gave details of the error that is being shown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    Session["your_array"] = new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0};


 double[] arr = double[](Session["your_array"]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You have probably worked out how to get the double array in, but may be having some trouble getting them back out - so here are examples of both:

```
        double[] myDoubleArray = new double[] { 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4};
        Session["DoubleList"] = myDoubleArray;

        double[] sessionDoubles = (double[])Session["DoubleList"];
```

Comment: thank you so much i implemented it thanks but my problem was that i am using seprate class for session variables and accessing data from there but any way i will implement it. thanks